# Linker Command failed while Archieving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, frameworks

I'm using a third-party framework which helps me to connect a device(Frameworks device). I'm getting

> MySignalsConnectKit' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks
>   and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install
>   build for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error while trying to achieving. I can successfully build. I searched it but still can't solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I change "Enable bitcode:" to NO as below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is probably because your third-party framework wasn't built with bitcode. If your application is archived with "Enable bitcode: YES" than all your frameworks must be built with bitcode also. Try to change it to NO, it may help. But then your archive will not contain bitcode. Better would be to get MySignalsConnectKit built with bitcode and use that build instead of one without bitcode.